# Predicate Logic : Satisfiability

Tags: general-topology, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

I have a set as :  **{∀x ∃y P(x, y), ∀x¬P(x, x)}.**  . In order to satisfy this set I know that there should exist an interpretation  **I**  such that it should satisfy all the elements in the set. For instance my interpretation for x is 3 and for y is 4. Should I apply the same numbers (3,4) to ∀x¬P(x, x) as well ? Moreover, there are two x's in the function argument so should I apply 3 and 3 which is the value of the x that I assigned ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Omega$ any set containing at least two elements, and $P(x,y):x\ne y$. You have one interpretation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Giving an interpretation means first of all specifying a set $I$ (the "*universe*") over which the variables range. In your case, you could choose $I = \{3,4\}$. Next, you have to choose how to interpret all the predicate symbols. *Predicate symbols* (i.e., syntactical objects) must be interpreted by *relations over $I$* (i.e., semantical objects). For instance, you might interpret $P$ by the relation $P_I = \{(3,4),(4,3)\} \subseteq I^2$. And finally, you have to verify that all the formulas hold under this interpretation. In fact, they do: The first one holds, because **for every** $x \in I$ there **exists** some $y \in I$ such that $(x,y)$ is contained in $P_I$ (if $x = 3$, choose $y = 4$, if $x = 4$, choose $y = 3$). The second one holds as well, because **for every** $x \in I$, the pair $(x,x)$ is not contained in $P_I$.

Comment: So by same interpretation we mean applying the same truth condition for both formulas in the set ?

Comment: @CemAytekin I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand the part where we apply the same interpretation.What is our interpretation here ? And how are we using it to both formulas ?

Comment: @CemAytekin The interpretation consists of three components: (1) the universe $I$, (2) a relation $P_I$ for every predicate symbol $P$, and if there are function symbols also (3) a function $f_I$ for every function symbol $f$.

Comment: oh so the arguments x,y of the predicates P don't have to be the same ?

Comment: @CemAytekin The arguments $x,y$ are elements of the universe $I$. Note that, if there are several quantifications for one variable name (in your case, the $\forall x$ in the first and in the second formula), these are independent - you might as well replace every $x$ in the second formula by $z$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50734/discussion-between-cem-aytekin-and-uwe).